# Select a different value from different row in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how can I get the latest date in mysql?

In the image I just want to get MEMB_N, LAST_M and the latest date which is under id = 655369, 2019-7-29.

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for one row, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.printdate is not null
order by t.printdate desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: If you think this is the best solution to your problem. Then accept it by clicking on the checkmark beside it to toggle it from greyed out to fill in. @Vin